# Why I can't access internet using an static IP address?

Tags: networking, static-ip

I want to set up my machine with a static IP address. I've done it before and it worked.

It's been a long time so, once again, I researched how to do it before starting. It looked pretty familiar and I could remember the process from before ... so I got started ...

I should mention that this is a new installation. The only thing I did before attempting this was to do an update and install ssh.

The first thing that I thought was odd was the contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`.  It looked like this:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Where's the stuff I usually find (and the walk through pages all seemed indicate that I would find) for eth0? I was expecting to see:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Funny thing is, it did pick up an IP address - `192.169.1.100` - which is a bit odd because IPs are usually assigned on a sequential basis and I would have expected it to pick up `192.168.1.7` because this was the next available IP.

Anyway, all this oddness aside, I ploughed on. I added the following to `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.201
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 192.168.1.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Then the next dose of oddness ... I issued the following command: `/etc/init.d/networking restart` ... nothing happened. No error messages, nothing at all. So, I tried this: `service networking restart` ... this is what happened:

```
stop: Job failed while stopping
start: Job is already running: networking
```

So I rebooted. The network configuration looked just great. I could ssh into the machine from inside my internal network. At this moment I thought I'd done it and I could forget the odd stuff. But no, the next thing I did was run apt-get update ... it failed ... I tried to ping a couple of websites and nothing would resolve so I'm guessing it's not finding a DNS server.

But it's just a guess and it doesn't help me because I don't know what to try next.

Comment: Thanks user68186 - I've taken that approach before but it introduced another set of problems (that I do understand for a change!) that I want to avoid this time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The default `/etc/network/interfaces` file only contains the loopback interface definition because desktop versions of Ubuntu use the `NetworkManager` service instead.

Your current configuration is missing a `dns-nameservers` specification, so it cannot resolve names to IP addresses.

You could add one or more `dns-nameservers`, however unless you have a particular reason to use the networking service, it would probably be better to revert your changes and then set up a static interface via NetworkManager's `nm-applet` (from the menu bar) or by invoking `nm-connection-editor` from a terminal - navigate to the `IPV4 Settings` tab and change the drop-down `Method:` from `DHCP` to `Manual` and then enter your desired network parameters there.

Comment: Ah - now this makes sense - when I did all this before I didn't have a gui installed - this time I installed the lot. Right, I'm going to try adding a dns-nameserver just because I want to see this through but I'll probably re-install without the gui. This machine is inteded to be a file server for a small network of windows pcs and macs. Is there any reason to use or not to use a gui for this role? I am more comfortable with command line stuff for this kind of thing but I thought that the gui might help with some other stuff that I might do on the machine. Thanks steeldriver

Comment: If you're comfortable administering everything via CLI that's fine. FYI the keyword in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file needs to be `dns-nameservers` (plural) even if you only specify a single one e.g. `dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1` or `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4`

Comment: Excellent - that worked - I simply added this: dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8, restarted and it worked. I am a very happy, I can go to bed now! :) I will get shot of the gui tomorrow. Thank you so much steeldriver. By the way, is it possible to mark this as solved? I've looked for a button/link but, either I'm too tired to see it or it's not there.

Comment: @Simon Yes! Please, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) :) you can also upvote it

Comment: Thanks Lucio, I have accepted it. It seems I can't upvote it because I don't have enough reputation - you should ask our local rozzers (police if you're not English), they'd tell you differently! :)

Comment: By the way, this forum is really, really good - lots of helpful people who don't ridicule us beginners - thanks to everyone involved.

Comment: Seriously, applying the same configuration on a windows machine to see if it works because it is more stable makes Ubuntu a disgrace.