# Unable to set static ip on ubuntu 14.10

Tags: networking, 14.10, static-ip

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 14.10 and have been trying to set a static IP but it does not connect when I try.

My interfaces file looks like this:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.0.146
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
```

And when I try to sudo service networking restart is gives error that it is unable to stop networking.

```
 ➜  ~  sudo service networking restart
   stop: Job failed while stopping
   start: Job is already running: networking
 ➜  ~  
 ➜  ~
```

I have also tried using the program wicd-curses and on setting a static IP I lose connection.

my connection info is correct (I have other systems running with the same connection info)

Any help is appreciated

**Edit** as a clarification - I am able to connect to my local network using this config ^^ however not the internet

**Edit** Version 14.10, not 14.04

Comment: Is this a server or desktop install?

Comment: Desktop install

Comment: You'll need to configure the network IP to static for ethernet through the Network Manager GUI, then.

Comment: Try not having the space between `iface eth0 inet static` and the address and other arguments.  You can use spaces to indent, but that extra whitespace may break it.  As well, you could always use Network Manager's GUI configuration for the ethernet connection.

Comment: I have tried configuring with the network manager GUI but it does not work either

Comment: Also for your last comment that does not work either. Still no connection

Comment: Did you reboot?  You'll have to restart after editing `/etc/network/interfaces` - network manager it'll just work after you remove and reconnect the ethernet interface.

Comment: I have tried rebooting with this method. Still no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your problem is, the line you have inserted in `/etc/network/interfaces` file **auto eth0**
Basically you are saying the "eth0" interface will be automatically configured ( via dhcp pool).

Try this

> ```
> auto lo
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> # Primary Network
> iface eth0 inet static
> address 192.168.2.13   #this ip might be different according to your router
> netmask 255.255.255.0
> gateway 192.168.2.1    
> network 192.168.2.0
> ```

Now restart the networking services using

> sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart

or you may have to `reboot the ubuntu Machine` as well in order for changes to take affect.

Thanks. Good Luck

Comment: `auto eth0` is valid here - it means its autoconfigured based on the next lines.  The next line determines static vs. dhcp.  IN a desktop setup, however, Network Manager dominates control instead of `/etc/network/interfaces` typically.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it @thomas. With the above lines mentioned in the  configuration should change the IP to static.

Comment: Except they already have this above - they have an extra space between iface... and address, which might be the problem.

Comment: I have tried this above option previously. Same result

Comment: then try 

`sudo ifconfig eth0 192.168.0.146 netmask 255.255.255.0`

Comment: After running this command I immediately lose internet connection.

Comment: if your ip was changed to what you said then post the output of your routing table.
type `sudo route`

Comment: The output of sudo route after running the above command is:

'Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0'

Comment: ok so now the problem in here is basically, not having a particluar gateway. Try `sudo route add 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.0.1` or `sudo route add 192.168.0.0 gw 192.168.0.1`
restart the networking services /etc/init.d/networking restart

Try pinging the localhost, your router and external Ip address such as www.google.com

Comment: after running that command I am able to ping my router and localhost but still have no internet connection. (I ran the second command as the first did not work) **note** I then tried a reboot after which my route tables went back to the way they were before running the second command

Comment: My route table after running command:

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

Comment: this is strange! when you ping google.com what does it say? unable to resolv the hostname?

Comment: Yes it is very strange! Never had any problems of this sort. pinging google gives unable to resolve hostname yes

Comment: I just noticed I made a mistake in my specified version. I am running 14.10 not 14.04. Does this change anything? I will edit this in my original post

Comment: i think the version should not matter. check the `/etc/resolv.conf` and add the line at last `nameserver 8.8.8.8 #google dns server` and `nameserver 192.168.0.1 #whatever is your router ip` `search 192.168.0.1 ` Restart the networking service

Comment: that isn't clear to me. You mention two nameserver config sections? My resolv.conf looks like this:

nameserver 192.168.0.1
search Sitecom

Comment: under your name server file this is the router's dns ip,basically for dns queries and the 8.8.8.8 is for google dns nameserver.

Comment: Ok well I changed my resolv.conf to look like this:

nameserver 8.8.8.8    
nameserver 192.168.0.1
search 192.168.0.1

Comment: on network restart, the resolv.conf file got overwriten

Comment: Ok after editing the resolv.conf with wicd-curses I was able to connect using the static IP. However - Port forwarding to the specified IP is not working and on reboot it removed my static ip and rewrote the resolv.conf file

Comment: basically, overall, we assigned the static ip to the interface without mentioning the gateway, then added the route to define the gateway for that network to go out, sometime if router's dns doesn't repond, we may try adding the google dns. This is just a work around, I had the same problem for my VMS but made it work. I am glad if its working. for you. have fun :)

Comment: Ok that makes sense thanks. I still got 2 problems on top of this though. I can't port forward to the static IP (I'm guessing for some reason my router doesn't have complete access to the IP or something) and 2 resolv.conf gets rewritten on reboot. any way to permanently edit it?

Comment: you can add an entry for "nameserver" under your static ip address file `/etc/network/interface` just below the network.

Answer (score 1):

First You must check if Network Manager is managing your network interface.

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nmcli dev status
```

The above command will list all existing network interfaces along with their state.
If state is shown as unmanaged, this means Network Manager is not controlling a corresponding interface. 
If state displays any other values:

```
DEVICE     TYPE              STATE
eth0      802-3-ethernet   connected
```

It implies that a given interface is managed by Network Manager.

To disable Network Manager for your eth0, you can do the following.

Edit the Network Manager configuration file in /etc/NetworkManager, and set:

```
managed=false
```

In the terminal continue running:

```
nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

And write the following lines:

```
[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>, save file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>, close nano.

Then in /etc/network/interfaces, add information about the interface you want to disable Network Manager for.

In the terminal continue running:

```
nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

And write the following lines:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# eth0 not managed by Network Manager
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.146
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 208.67.222.222 #DNS OpenDns
```

Now Network Manager automatically ignore any interfaces specified in file:

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

And stop managing them.

After rebooting, verify that Network Manager is successfully disabled for eth0:

```
sudo -i
nmcli dev status


DEVICE     TYPE              STATE
eth0      802-3-ethernet   unmanaged
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo ifdown eth0 && sudo ifup eth0`

If that fails `sudo service network-manager restart`

Comment: Tried both of those already. Does not work

Comment: What does `cat /var/log/syslog | grep networking` show? It may be a part of [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/1301015) well-documented bug. If interested, you can use [this workaround](https://github.com/metral/restore_networking) that someone has created to recreate 13.10 behavior.

Comment: Jan 14 21:54:15 lupi kernel: [ 1467.579924] init: networking post-stop process (13204) terminated with status 100
Jan 14 21:54:26 lupi kernel: [ 1477.929474] init: networking post-stop process (13223) terminated with status 100
Jan 14 21:54:37 lupi kernel: [ 1488.812537] init: networking post-stop process (13242) terminated with status 100

Comment: See [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171846/unable-to-restart-networking-daemon) about the source of the exit 100.

Comment: I will take a look but my main problem isn't that the network isn't restarting (I can "force" it with a reboot) it's that static IP's do not connect to the internet

Comment: Are you sure your network, subnet mask, and gateway is correct?

Comment: I am 100% sure.

Comment: You're using desktop, try to set up a static interface via NetworkManager's `nm-applet` (from the menu bar) or by invoking `nm-connection-editor` from a terminal - navigate to the IPV4 Settings tab and change the drop-down Method: from `DHCP` to `Manual` and then enter your desired network parameters there. ([source](http://askubuntu.com/questions/499701/why-i-cant-access-internet-using-an-static-ip-address))

Comment: Tried this with No Result. Next to the created connection under the "last connected" field is never.

Comment: can you show the output for routing table after setting up the static ip ????

Comment: Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

Answer (score 0):

First of all you must check your adapter name with help of sudo ip link command,

`# sudo ip link`

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 78:2b:cc:5e:02:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Now we come to know that our adapter is em1

so changes your adapter name in file configuration :

`# cat /et/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

`# Primary Network`

```
auto em1
iface em1 inet static
address 192.168.2.13   #this ip might be different according to your router
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1    
network 192.168.2.0
```

---

```
## sudo ifdown em1
## sudo ifup em1
```

---

You will be good to go